# Rails rspec expecte().to with :where and .first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, automated-tests

I'm a beginner in Rails, but I need a re-write old tests.
Problem is have no idea how to do this. 
For example how to write destroy part: **News.where(:id => 123).first**

```
expect(News).to receive(:where).with('123')..?
```

Look "**it "should destroy news" do**" in the test.

Any ideas how to improve this test is much appreciated!

**Here is part of news_controller_spec.rb**

```
    it "should destroy news" do
      News.should_receive(:find).with('123').and_return(@model)
      @model.should_receive(:destroy).and_return(true)
      delete :destroy, :id => 123, :step => 1
      response.should redirect_to(news_index_path)
    end
```

**Here is News controller**

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'layouts/news'

  skip_before_filter :login_required, :only => [:show, :index]
  before_filter :require_admin, :except => [:show, :index]
  before_filter :load_model, :only => [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]

  def destroy
    @news.destroy
    redirect_to(@news, :notice => I18n.t(:news_deleted))
  end

protected
  def load_model
    @news = News.where(:id => params[:id]).first
    if @news.nil?
      redirect_to(news_index_url)
    end
  end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:news).permit! if params[:news] #(:title,:content,:language)
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant code related to your problem. Having people dig through all your code is probably the reason you have 0 replies as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to mock the method be expecting the params it would receive in the real implementation. In this case `where` will receive an hash which specifies the id of the model to load. This will return an array with your double (since you are going to call first method). You can now expect to have the `destroy` method been called on your double.

```
describe '#destroy' do
  let(:news) { double('news', nil?: false) }

  context 'when called with known id' do 
    before do 
      allow(News).to receive(:where).with(id: 123).and_return([news])
      allow(news).to receive(:destroy)
    end      

    it 'should destroy corresponding news entry' do
      delete :destroy, id: 123
      expect(response).to redirect_to(news_index_path)
      expect(news).to have_received(:destroy)
    end
  end
end
```

(not sure if you need to mock `nil?` though but got no console to test it right now)